# How to convert a string into a parameter of a function?

Tags: python, string, function, parameters

I have to subtract 2 dates using datetime like this:

```
datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
# subtracting 15 minutes
```

The problem is that i don't necessarily need to subtract minutes.
I have a dictionary that tells what i should subtract.

```
period = {'quantity': '15', 'time': 'minutes'}
```

But i need that when the dictionary changes, the subtracted time also changes. Like this:

```
if period['time'] == 'minutes':
    tempo_atras = datetime.datetime.now() -datetime.timedelta(minutes=int(period['quantity']))
elif period['time'] == 'hours':
    tempo_atras = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=int(period['quantity']))
elif period['time'] == 'days':
    tempo_atras = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=int(period['quantity']))
elif period['time'] == 'weeks':
    tempo_atras = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(weeks=int(period['quantity']))
```

I feel that the way i wrote it is not clean, so i need a way to convert the `period['time']` string in the function parameter; something like:

```
tempo_atras = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(period['time']=int(period['quantity']))
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the dictionary unpacking operator `**` to expand a dict into keyword arguments, so you just need to make the dict first.

```
q = {period['time']: int(period['quantity'])}
tempo_atras = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(**q)
```

Docs:

- Tutorial: [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)
- Reference: [Calls](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls)

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert the dictionary so that the period is pointing to the quantity. Then use dictionary unpacking normally.

```
import datetime
period = {'quantity': '15', 'time': 'minutes'}
# convert the dictionary to a dictionary of "minutes"= "15"
period = {period['time']: int(period['quantity'])}
print(period)
tempo_atras = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(**period)
```

Note: you can read more about this format (and the `*` format for lists) here: [More on Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions)

Comment: You don't need to reuse the name `period`, in fact I'd recommend against it to avoid confusion.